# Add vertical scroll bar in web page using IE11

Tags: css, overflow, internet-explorer-11

i have this code in my web page application

```
html, body, form
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow:scroll;
}
```

but nothing happens when i add overflow:scroll. I also tries to use overflow-y:scroll but CSS 2.1 does't have this property. When i run F12 in IE11 and manually add overflow-y:scroll; it's work but i application just adding overflow:scroll; doesn't work. Any solution ?

Answer (score 0):

You could try to improve your selector.

Do you have any css libraries that could erase your css declaration ? You want scroll on those 3 tags : `html`, `body` and `form` ?